# Page loads with old bean data

Tags: spring, jsf, javabeans

I have two pages, say page-1 and page-2. I fill some values in page-1 and redriect to page-2. Based on values selected in page-1, the page-2 data will be populated and shown.

When the page-2 load, it displays no data or old data from the bean. But the page-2 displays correct data only after manual refresh (F5 key).

```
Page-1 --> Page-2 ==== Displays old bean data
Page-1 --> Page-2 --> F5 key or Refresh ==== Displays new or correct bean data
```

I have `@PostConstruct` in the controller method which populates the bean. And bean is not managedbean or sessionscoped bean as of now.

`Page-1.xhtml`

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h:form id="myForm">
    <p:outputLabel value="#{mybean.myvalue}"></p:outputLabel>
</h:form>
<p:commandButton value="Login" type="submit"
    actionListener="#{page1Controller.myListener}"
    style="float:right;margin-right:30px;" update="myForm">
</p:commandButton>
</body>
</html>
```

`Page-2.xhtml`

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h:inputhidden value="#{page2Controller.myListener()}"></h:inputhidden>
    <h:form id="myForm">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{mybean.myvalue}"></p:outputLabel>
    </h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Back" id="back" style="margin-left:30px;"
        action="page-1.xhtml?faces-redirect=true">
    </p:commandButton>
</body>
</html>
```

`Page1Bean.java`

```
@Component
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {
    private String page1Value = null;

    public void setPage1Value(String page1Value ) {
        this.page1Value = page1Value ;
    }

    public String getPage1Value() {
        return this.page1Value ;
    }
}
```

`Page1Controller.java`

```
public class Page1Controller {

    public void myListener() {
                page1Bean.setPage1Value("new value");
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        externalContext.redirect(externalContext
                        .getRequestContextPath() + "page2.xhtml");
    }
}
```

`Page2Bean.java`

```
@Component
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {
    private String page2Value = null;

    public void setPage2Value(String page2Value ) {
        this.page2Value = page2Value ;
    }

    public String getPage2Value() {
        return this.page2Value ;
    }
}
```

`Page2Controller.java`

```
@Controller
public class Page2Controller {

    public void myListener() {
        page2Bean.setPage2Value(page1Bean.getPage1Value());
    }
}
```

In above code, the outputlabel in page2.xhtml is not getting updated with the backing bean value when the page gets loaded initally. But the correct value is displayed after refreshing the page.

I use JSF and Spring.

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: please provide the code of page 2 at least.

Comment: @tt_emrah Added sample code.

Comment: What about adding `faces-redirect=true` also to the name page specified in the method `myListener()` of the bean `Page1Controller` ?

Comment: @Omar no luck. It does not work. Basically i have page1 bean and page2 bean. I query the DB with the page1 bean value. If i hardcode this bean value in my query everything works. If i take the value from page1 bean, the issue occurs.

Comment: Those two beans seem to have the same name ?! I suggest using one bean for the pages that are concerned by the same bean properties.

Comment: @Omar Both are different beans. names are different. Please note the numbers in the bean name, Page1 and Page2. There are also some other properties in each bean.

Comment: Have you tried changing the scope to request ?

Comment: @Omar yes.. i tried viewScope, requestScope and managedbean. But nothing worked out.